# Mysql Python Connector No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, mysql, connection, port

first i did

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

and then I made a file names "my.py" containing the following code

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="abc",
  password="1234"
)

print(mydb)
```

and im getting the following error
***ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it***

I have already closed firewalls, I have tried on 127.0.0.1, my LAN is not on proxy settings, and im not able to run connect on either port 3306 or 33060 or 22.

[Here's everything from MYSql Installer - Community that I have installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUhSE.png)

Comment: The error indicates that there is no MySQL server running on localhost. You didn't mention installing MySQL or starting the server.

Comment: I have installed mysql from the mysql installer - community with the "developer" option. How do i run the mysql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 2 possible options:

1. Database is not running (as proposed by [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166356/john)).
2. Your database is not running directly on your pc but on a VM or docker image.
   In that case, user shall not be bound to 'localhost' but to '%' that stands for 'any location'. This is because VMs and docker containers run in a separate environment, and 'localhost' users login is accepted from the host running the database only.
   Obviously this introduces a security concern since that login will be accepted from any place (localhost, other PCs in private network and other PCs on the internet network).

Comment: thanks a lot. after re configuring the server and making changes in username/password my connection is now up!

Comment: 2nd option would result in an access denied message, not in a connection refused one.

Comment: @Shadow, i did modify the answer as per your comment, thank you